# Endstop switched

Tags: switches, automation, cnc

I have a cnc machine and I need to connect an end stop switched to the motor and stages.
first I need a simulation for this, that each snd stop is connected to a stage (x,y,z) and when the switch is closed the stage is stop moving. how can I do this using Multisim ?

Answer (score 0):

You don’t simulate it in Multisim.

You mount the switch, if mechanical, add a small ecap for de bouncing, then program in your GCode controller program.  I prefer GCode Panel for Win.

Comment: Is that kind of an open-source Mach 3, Tony?

Comment: Yes It’s the best Open Source code I’ve seen and best GCode App too. I chose it for a U of T custom gantry designed and supplied for their WPT program. It used an Uno with CNC Shield with GCode uploaded

Comment: @SpehroPefhany https://youtu.be/kGbxkIHce9U

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'll try it out.